# C++ kafka consumer - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, segmentation-fault, coredump, consumer

I wrote C++ consumer for kafka messages using cppkafka library (wrapper for librdkafka). I have problem while running program. Sometimes there is problem with Segmentation fault (core dumped) before topic assigned, but sometimes it runs without any errors. Below You can find my main() code.

```
bool running = true;


int main() {
string topic = "topic";
string stop = "STOP";
int m_count = 0;

signal(SIGINT, [](int) { running = false; });


Configuration config = {
        { "metadata.broker.list", "kafka-1:19092"},
        {"group.id", topic},
        {"fetch.wait.max.ms", 10},
        {"enable.auto.commit", false},
        {"auto.offset.reset", "latest"}
};

Consumer consumer(config);


consumer.set_assignment_callback([](const TopicPartitionList& partitions) {
    cout << "Got assigned: " << partitions << endl;
});

consumer.set_revocation_callback([](const TopicPartitionList& partitions) {
    cout << "Got revoked: " << partitions << endl;
});

consumer.subscribe({ topic });

cout << "Consuming messages from topic " << topic << endl;

auto ms = std::chrono::microseconds(10);

while (running) {

    Message msg = consumer.poll();
    if (msg) {
        if (msg.get_error()) {
            if (!msg.is_eof()) {
                cout << "[+] Received error notification: " << msg.get_error() << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            m_count ++;
            cout << msg.get_payload()<<" OFSET: "<< msg.get_offset() <<" TIME: "<<getMs() - msg.get_timestamp().get().get_timestamp().count()<< endl;
            consumer.commit(msg);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is this right? `msg.get_timestamp().get().get_timestamp().count()`

Comment: It is correct, it works correct when segmentation fault does't appear.

Comment: I couldn't find this function in cppkafka API but CLion suggest it.

Comment: You don't seem to delete the msgs you get from poll(), so maybe your application is running out of memory?

Comment: I'm running out of ideas how to do it, any tips ?